# An Example Where $Df$ Is Not Integrable

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I have been trying to find an example where $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and is differentiable on $(0,1)$, however, $Df$ (gradient) is not integrable on $[0,1].$

I thought of one example: $f(x,y)=arctan(xy).$ Am I right? Some more examples more help.

Comment: So are you looking for a function defined on $[0,1]$, or $[0,1]\times [0,1]$?

Comment: A function on [0,1].

Comment: By writing $f(x,y)$, you suggest that your function is defined in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Regardless, the classic example is Volterra's Function, which is thoroughly discussed in its Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Juila The gradient of $\arctan(xy)$ is nicely integrable over $[0,1]^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Some hints, on the assumption that "integrability" means "Riemann integrability". (Throughout, $f$ denotes a continuous, real-valued function on $[0, 1]$ that is differentiable on $(0, 1)$, and $g$ denotes an arbitrary function on $[0, 1]$.)

1. What properties are **necessary** for $g$ to be integrable? (The types of condition to consider include: continuity, continuity except at finitely many points, boundedness, etc.)

Rationale: If you construct a function $f$ such that $g := f'$ does not satisfy a necessary condition for integrability, you're done.

2. What properties are **sufficient** for $g$ to be integrable? (Again, consider properties such as continuity, continuity except at finitely many points, boundedness, etc.)

Rationale: If you construct a function $f$ such that $g := f'$ satisfies a sufficient condition for integrability, you do not have a counterexample. In retrospect, this means that if you start writing down differentiable functions naively, you're sort of unlikely to stumble across an example of the type you seek, because $f'$ is likely to be integrable.

3. The formula
   $$
   g(x) = \begin{cases}
     x^{2} \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0, \\
     0 & x = 0,
   \end{cases}
   $$
   is well-known (and easily shown; calculate the derivative yourself) to define a function differentiable *everywhere* in $\Reals$, but to have discontinuous derivative at $0$.

Unfortunately, the derivative of this $g$ is integrable. Fortunately, a suitable modification (there are multiple possibilities) will produce a function of the type you seek.

(Limiting this answer to the preceding hints is my attempt to help you think systematically without depriving you the pleasure of finding an actual counterexample yourself, and thereby *seeing why* your function is a counterexample.)

Comment: Wait... but the derivative of g is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Yes. As the second-to-last paragraph states, "Unfortunately, the derivative of this $g$ is integrable. Fortunately, a suitable modification (there are multiple possibilities) will produce a function of the type you seek." :)

Comment: I meant it isn't integrable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function

Comment: 1. $g$ is not the Volterra function. 2. The modifications I had in mind are more naive than the construction of the Volterra function. (The aptness of my suggestion does depend, however, on whether "integrability" means "Riemann integrability". If that's not the case, could you please edit your question?)

Comment: To my understanding, if a function is integrable, it is also considered Riemann integrable as well. Is that wrong?

Comment: If "integrable" means "Lebesgue integrable", then no, that does not imply Riemann integrability. (The Dirichlet function is the standard counterexample.)

Comment: I just meant Riemann integrable.